# Solubility From Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is the question I am attempting to solve

Determine which values of $k$, if any, will give:

a) A unique solution, 
 b) No solution,
 c) Infinitely many solutions to the system of equations.

$$\begin{align} x+y+kz& =2 \\ \\ 3x+4y+2z& =k \\ \\ 2x+3y-z& =1\end{align}$$

I transformed this into row-echelon form. I got.

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & k &2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2-3k &k-6 \\ 
0 & 0 & -3+k & 3-k
\end{pmatrix}

The answers say for a unique solution $k \neq 3$

a) So my reasoning is that if $k$ is not equal to $3$.Then we obviously have a unique solution, because if $k=3$, we would have everything in row $3$ equal to $0$. Hence we need to introduce parameters to solve the equation thus making us have infinitely many solutions.

b) No solutions occurs if we have in the last row $(0,0,0|\alpha)$, where $alpha \neq 0$. We can't have any values of k that can attain this result.

c) See a).

Is this the right reasoning?

Comment: Have you double-checked your row-echelon form?

Comment: I will do so now.

Comment: I think the third column of the third row is off.

Comment: Yup sorry it is meant to be -3+k.

Comment: Uh, I can't find anymore mistakes. Mmm,

Comment: If you have found a mistake in the question, please edit the question to fix it.

Comment: I understand now. I will fix my error. In entry [3][3] I it should be -3+k and the corresponding right hand column it should be 3-k

Comment: I think it's fixed now, could anyone see if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Can you see, now, why $k = 3$, there are infinitely many solutions (third row: row of zeros)? (Hence no unique solution)?

Comment: Yes, if we put k=3, we will have to solve the system as follows:

(I'll edit it in - hold on my net is playing up)

Comment: If k=3

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  & 3 & 2 \\ 
 0&1  & -7 & -2 \\ 
 0&0  &0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Let $x_{3}=\lambda$

We get $x_{2}=-2-7\lambda, x_{1}=...$ Hence we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Yes, indeed! (I posted my question in my last comment before I saw your edited reasoning.) Nice work, makes sense now, doesn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

With corrections in your REF, your answers are indeed correct. I suspect that the errors in your initial REF clears up the initial concern you had.

I would include the unique solution in part $(a)$, and include your reasoning for $(c)$ in part $(c)$: in $(a)$, mention that "at $k = 3$, there are infinitely many solutions, (i.e., $0\cdot z = 0 \implies$ any $z$ in the domain is a solution, hence no single unique solution: see part(c))."

I would mention the word ***inconsistent*** in part $(b)$: the system of linear equations would be *inconsistent* (there would be no solution for $z$ such that $0\times z = c$ where $c\neq 0$ - hence no solution for the system of equations), and so since there is no value of $k$ for which that can happen, the system must either have a unique solution ($k \neq 3$) or infinitely many solutions, if and only if $k = 3$.

Comment: Cheers amWhy, I thought this was REF not RREF?

Comment: Yes, you're correct: REF, in this case (almost RREF).

Comment: @amWhy:$\Large{+1}^{\Large{☺}}$$ⓃⒾⒸⒺ$

Comment: Thanks, @flashdesign2550 $\large\color{blue}{\diamondsuit_\diamondsuit^\diamondsuit\diamondsuit}$

Comment: @amWhy: I see you have been playing around with LaTex! Nice design! :-) +1

Comment: Wow.$\Large\color{red}{✿}$ᐯᙓᖇ૪ ﬡᓮᑕᙓ$\Large\color{red}{✿}$@amWhy